# Converting HTML table to CSV file from shell

Tags: linux, bash, csv, libreoffice

im trying to convert a file with an HTML table to CSV format. An excerpt from this file follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /><title>
Untitled Page
    </title></head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="mypricelist.aspx" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/somethingrandom" />

<div>
    <table id="price_list" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>ProdCode</td><td>Description</td><td>Your Price</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>ab101</td><td>loruem</td><td>1.1</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>ab102</td><td>ipsum</td><td>0.1</td>
</tr><tr>
```

i tried using

```
    xls2csv -x -c\; evprice.xls > evprice.csv
```

but that gives me an error saying

```
    evprice.xls is not OLE file or Error
```

I googled. it said that is was because the file wasn't proper xls but just html.

When i try

```
    file evprice.xls
```

its says its html so found a 'solution', using libreoffice.

```
    libreoffice --headless -convert-to csv ./evprice.xls
```

well this does not give an error but the csv output file is all weird, like opening an exe file in notepad.

it contains a lot of strange characters like these

```
    —¬ž­þ9ü~ÆóXþK¢
```

anyone know why this is happening, and got a working solution?

Comment: Is the sample data you're working with publicly available? I don't know how anyone would be able to provide something which would work with a file in an uncertain format whose content we've never seen.

Comment: sorry, its not public. i can place a part of the file

Comment: I wouldn't really describe that as an "XLS" file at all -- it's an HTML table, nothing Excel or XLS-related to it at all.

Comment: ...so, given that, this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259091/how-can-i-scrape-an-html-table-to-csv (though the accepted answer there isn't automated at all, there are others which are).

Comment: well, i don't know what kind of file it is. they say its a generated xls file but whatever. libreoffice can open it when i do it manually. why is it giving these weird characters when using the command line version?

Comment: *shrug*. That's a question about LibreOffice, not a question about programming. StackOverflow probably isn't the right place for it.

Comment: You might try http://ask.libreoffice.org/

Comment: [XSLT XML to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952365/how-do-i-write-an-xslt-to-transform-xml-to-csv)

Answer (score 1):

I have built a Python utility which converts all the tables in an HTML file into separate CSV files.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/html2csv).

The crux of the script is this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

filename = "MY_HTML_FILE"
fin      = open(filename,'r')

print "Opening file"
fin  = fin.read()

print "Parsing file"
soup = BeautifulSoup(fin,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

print "Preemptively removing unnecessary tags"
[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]

print "CSVing file"
tablecount = -1
for table in soup.findAll("table"):
  tablecount += 1
  print "Processing Table #%d" % (tablecount)
  with open(sys.argv[1]+str(tablecount)+'.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
      cols = row.findAll(['td','th'])
      if cols:
        cols = [x.text for x in cols]
        fout.writerow(cols)
```

Comment: Very useful indeed. I encountered some errors as in **"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character at special name..."**; however, I could fix it by adding these lines at the top of the file: `import sys; reload sys; sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`. The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137552/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-at-special-name/31137935#31137935) is what I actually did and suggest in this comment.