# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character at special name

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup, ascii

My python (ver 2.7) script is running well to get some company name from local html files but when it comes to some specific country name, it gives this error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character"

Specially getting error when this company name comes

Company Name: **Kühlfix Kälteanlagen Ing.Gerhard Doczekal & Co. KG**

The link cannot be processed

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python27\Process2.py", line 261, in <module>
    flog.write("\nCompany Name: "+str(pCompanyName))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Error gives in this line of code:**

```
if companyAlreadyKnown == 0:
   for hit in soup2.findAll("h1"):
       print "Company Name: "+hit.text
       pCompanyName = hit.text
       flog.write("\nCompany Name: "+str(pCompanyName))
       companyObj.setCompanyName(pCompanyName)
```

Comment: Read http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: Anybody coming here should visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657010/dangers-of-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8, doing what is suggested in the accepted is usually if not always a **very bad idea**.

Comment: whereever you are writing to a file or reading from a file, you have to add encoding. open("filename", "w", encoding=''UTF-8")

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Try setting the system default encoding as `utf-8` at the start of the script, so that all strings are encoded using that.

Example -

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

The above should set the default encoding as `utf-8` .

Comment: now another error i am facing bro !   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Process2.py", line 261, in <module>
    print "Company Name: "+hit.text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 2
8: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You have changed the encoding to something else now - `charmap` so the issue occurs.

Comment: This works for Python 2.x, but it's not a great way to go about this and is deprecated in Python 3. Better to actually decode/encode the data properly. See discussion at [Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding(“utf-8”) in a py script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

Comment: @MartyMacGyver, totally correct, this can break libraries and cause hard to find bugs.  The fact that this is not even mentioned makes this a very dangerous answer.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that this is a potentially dangerous answer and you should instead decode/encode properly. However if the error is being raised from a library you have no control over (in my case pyspark), this is a handy short term work around.

Comment: This does not work: `module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

Comment: using `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` works for me

Comment: Nice and pretty simple, don't have to mess with encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 38):

You really want to do this

```
flog.write("\nCompany Name: "+ pCompanyName.encode('utf-8'))
```

This is the "encode late" strategy described in this [unicode presentation](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) (slides 32 through 35).

Comment: This is the correct approach and  should be the  accepted answer.

Comment: Correct approach - correct answer