# Google Translate API - EncodeError from a tranlated text

Tags: python, google-api, encode

I have some problems with the encoding text, inside a JSON, from a translation with Google Translate API and I'm a neophyte with Python and Google API too.

Below you can find a rudimental script that extract from a CSV the ID of a structure, SELECT the english description from the db and try to write the translated description in another table.

After the translation part:

```
t = service.translations().list(source='%s' % trans, \
        target='%s' % lang, q=[message2t]).execute()
translated = t['translations'][0]['translatedText']
```

I have my unicode variable `translated` with dirty chars in it (I have this problem with language like German or French). I don't know how to obtain the right chars.

Indeed, when I'm trying to write the string into the database, I obtain this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 225: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the full rudimental code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import _mysql
import time

trans = 'en'
langs = [ 'de', 'dk', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'no', 'pg', 'pl', 'sw' ]

# Google API Environment
key = 'MYKEY'
service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey=key)

# Open DB connection
db = _mysql.connect(user='MYUSER',
                    passwd='MYPASSWORD',
                    host='MYRDS',
                    port=3306,
                    db='MYDB')

for lang in langs:
  print 'Finding structures w/o description in {} language'.format(lang.upper())

  with open('nodesc_%s.csv' % lang, 'r') as structures:
    for structure in structures:
      id_str = structure.split('\t')[0]

      text2t = """SELECT `text` FROM `texts` WHERE
                  `str_ID`='%s' AND
                  `type`='description' AND
                  `lang`='%s';""" % (id_str, trans)
      db.query(text2t)
      r = db.store_result()
      message2t = r.fetch_row()[0][0]

      # Check if there is a description for real
      if len(message2t) is not 0:
        t = service.translations().list(source='%s' % trans, \
            target='%s' % lang, q=[message2t]).execute()
        translated = t['translations'][0]['translatedText']
        now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        texttranslated = """INSERT INTO `descriptions`
                            (`ID_desc`, `ID_str`, `text`, `lang`, `human_date`, `google_date`)
                            VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '%s')""" \
                            % (id_str, translated, lang, now)
        db.query(texttranslated)

      else:
        print 'Structure with id {} have no description in english'.format(id_str)

# Close DB connection
db.close()
```

Comment: I saw that ```type(tranlated)``` return a ```unicode```.

Comment: I tried ```translated..encode('ascii', 'ignore')``` but this ignore the char that I want to be written in the INSERT. 
There is something wrong with my knowledge, because if I try to ```print tranlated``` I have the correct string

Comment: I found this answer [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character at special name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137552/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-at-special-name) that works for me.