# Unicode-encode issues while sending desktop notification using Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I am fetching latest football scores from a website and sending a notification on the desktop (OS X). I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape the data. I had issues with the unicode data which was generating this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128).
```

So I inserted this at the beginning which solved the problem while outputting on the terminal.

```
import sys 
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

But the problem exists when I am sending notifications on the desktop. I use terminal-notifier to send desktop-notifications.

```
def notify (title, subtitle, message):
    t = '-title {!r}'.format(title)
    s = '-subtitle {!r}'.format(subtitle)
    m = '-message {!r}'.format(message)
    os.system('terminal-notifier {}'.format(' '.join((m, t, s))))
```

The below images depict the output on the terminal Vs the desktop notification.

Output on terminal.

[image]

Desktop Notification

[image: Dektop Notification]

Also, if I try to replace the comma in the string, I get the error,

`new_scorer = str(new_scorer[0].text).replace(",","")`

```
File "live_football_bbc01.py", line 41, in get_score
    new_scorer = str(new_scorer[0].text).replace(",","")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I get the output on the desktop notifications like the one on the terminal? Thanks!

***Edit : Snapshot of the desktop notification. (Solved)***

[image]

Comment: Don't call str, encode/decode as needed. Why are you calling str anyway? Also your reload logic is a terrible idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script. Another example of why answers like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31137935/2141635 should be deleted

Comment: Then I get proper output on terminal but on desktop notification the string beings with 'u', like` 'ukrkic' and 'uAg\xc3\b...`

Comment: Are you using python 2? If you are and don't need to be, this is one space where Python 3's default behaviour is much more convenient.

Comment: Oh yeah? I am using Python 2.7. Will look into that. Maybe its high time to switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting using `!r` which gives you the *repr* output, forget the terrible reload  logic and either use unicode everywhere:

```
def notify (title, subtitle, message):
    t = u'-title {}'.format(title)
    s = u'-subtitle {}'.format(subtitle)
    m = u'-message {}'.format(message)
    os.system(u'terminal-notifier {}'.format(u' '.join((m, t, s))))
```

or encode:

```
def notify (title, subtitle, message):
    t = '-title {}'.format(title.encode("utf-8"))
    s = '-subtitle {}'.format(subtitle.encode("utf-8"))
    m = '-message {}'.format(message.encode("utf-8"))
    os.system('terminal-notifier {}'.format(' '.join((m, t, s))))
```

When you call *str(new_scorer[0].text).replace(",","")* you are trying to encode to *ascii*, you need to specify the encoding to use:

```
In [13]: s1=s2=s3= u'\xfc'

In [14]: str(s1) # tries to encode to ascii
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-589849bdf059> in <module>()
----> 1 str(s1)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

In [15]: "{}".format(s1) + "{}".format(s2) + "{}".format(s3) # tries to encode to ascii---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7ca3746f9fba> in <module>()
----> 1 "{}".format(s1) + "{}".format(s2) + "{}".format(s3)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can encode straight away:

```
In [16]: "{}".format(s1.encode("utf-8")) + "{}".format(s2.encode("utf-8")) + "{}".format(s3.encode("utf-8"))
Out[16]: '\xc3\xbc\xc3\xbc\xc3\xbc'
```

Or use use all unicode prepending a u to the format strings and encoding last:

```
In [17]: out = u"{}".format(s1) + u"{}".format(s2) + u"{}".format(s3)
In [18]: out
Out[18]: u'\xfc\xfc\xfc'

In [19]: out.encode("utf-8")
Out[19]: '\xc3\xbc\xc3\xbc\xc3\xbc'
```

If you use `!r` you are always going to the the bytes in the output:

```
In [30]: print "{}".format(s1.encode("utf-8"))
ü

In [31]: print "{!r}".format(s1).encode("utf-8")
u'\xfc'
```

You can also pass the args using subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_call


def notify (title, subtitle, message):
    cheek_call(['terminal-notifier','-title',title.encode("utf-8"),
                '-subtitle',subtitle.encode("utf-8"),
                '-message'.message.encode("utf-8")])
```

Comment: I am using repr to get the quotes for the string so that it matches the terminal-notifier syntax `terminal-notifier -[message|list|remove] [VALUE|ID|ID] [options]`. Otherwise I would get the error, `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `terminal-notifier -message Krkic (49' minutes pen) -title Stoke Vs Man City -subtitle 1-4 FT'`

Comment: Using the encoding version, I still get the same output on the desktop notifier.

Comment: Well use subprocess not os.system and pass a lsit of args to subprocess.check_call

Comment: Everything is working fine except for the desktop notification. I suspect if the  terminal-notifier has inbuilt encoding/decoding issues.

Comment: @build_code, in your question what you see are the utf-8 encoded bytes from the repr output, if you printed a tuple with those elements you would see the same output so i don't think it has anything to do with encoding as the encoded bytes are correct, somehow the repr output is getting outputted from the ruby program

Comment: Yes the `repr` function is modifying the string. I tried with concatenating with `" ' "+'-message { }'.format(repr(message.encode("utf-8")))+ " ' "` to get the quoted string but didn't seem to work, shows syntax error. Any other alternative to make the terminal-notifier execute or alternatives for desktop notifier ?

Comment: Finally got it !! used `m =  '-message'+ " '"+message.encode("utf-8")+ "'"` and worked. I am able to get the desktop notification like the one on the terminal.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the explanation and details and for spending your time. Helped !!

Comment: Didn't use the subprocess code because the issue was with repr as you pointed out.  Os.system wasn't causing any problems.

Comment: No worries. I was just going to say split the title and encoded string into separate arts and the subprocess code will work fine. I prefer subprocess as it is less error prone and simpler to pass args.

Comment: For reference, I have edited the question that includes the desktop notification that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use: ˋsys.getfilesystemencoding` to get your encoding

Encode your string with it, ignore or replace errors:

```
import sys

encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
msg = new_scorer[0].text.replace(",", "")
print(msg.encode(encoding, errons="replace"))
```