# How to decode Japanese Yen symbol in Python?

Tags: python, encoding

I got a bytes data including Japanese Yen symbol (¥). This seems to be expressed as `\xc2\xa5`.

However, I can't decode the yen symbol. For example,

```
yen = b"\xc2\xa5"
type(yen) # return bytes
yen.decode("utf-8") # return UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa5' error
import chardet
chardet.detect(yen) # return {'confidence': 0.73, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
yen.decode("windows-1252") # return another UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters error
```

The bytes data I have can be decoded as `utf-8` in other aspects. Only Japanese Yen symbol cannot be decoded, no matter what encoding you use.

So how can I decode it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `b"\xc2\xa5"` is UTF-8 encoding of `¥`. `yen.decode("utf-8")` yields `¥` (or `u'\xa5'`) in both Python2 and Python3 for me, both on Debian and OSX. What is your `sys.stdout.encoding`? It looks like it could be an error in output, rather than string manipulation itself.

Comment: @Amadan Oh, really? I double-checked it but still got the same error. I use Python 3.5 (IPython interactive shell) on macOS.

Comment: `YEN=yen.decode('utf-8')` works fine for me.

Comment: @Amadan It got me `'US-ASCII'`.

Comment: Try running as `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 ipython`?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31137935/3209112) also :)

Comment: @Blaszard See the accepted answer there, it tells about updating .bash_profile.

Comment: So what is your `LANG`? Empty? `zh_CN.UTF-8`? Something else?

Comment: @ABcDexter @Amadan Sorry for that the problem was in my Terminal and shell settings, not in Python. My `LANG` setting was `en_US.UTF-8` but I didn't add `export` keyword. It got me the correct value (`en_US.UTF-8`) when trying to print out `echo $LANG`, but for some reasons `sys.stdout.encoding` returns `UTF-8` only when you add `export` keyword in `~/.zprofile`. Thanks for the instruction, though. Everything works fine now.

Comment: @Blaszard Consider answering your own question, since it might be helpful for future readers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the settings in Terminal and the shell. Specifically, in order to make the decoding work as expected, your `sys.stdout.encoding` should return `UTF-8`.

If you don't get `UTF-8`, then you should check out `$LANG` variable. In my case it returned `en_US.UTF-8`, but since my `~/.zprofile` didn't have `export` keyword, `sys.stdout.encoding` returned `US-ASCII`, not `UTF-8`. So you should set in your `~/.zprofile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) as:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

And now you should get `UTF-8` from `sys.stdout.encoding`.

For more information on setting a correct locale in your shell and Terminal on macOS, check out [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error).