# ASCII codes convertion

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

Hi I am trying to save images through URL on python 2.7. There are some urls like containing special characters. 
like : `http://homegrown.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Pl%C3%B6tzlich-Am-Meer.jpg` and there are lots of url with some special character.

I am saving URL by following code and I am getting error:

```
def save_image_from_url(url, filename):
print('Saving {} locally'.format(url))
image = requests.get(url)
with open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR_ABS, filename), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image.content)
    f.close()
```

Error

```
File "/home/wp-migrate/migrate.py", line 340, in seperate_img_blocks
    save_image_from_url(url, filename)
  File "/home/wp-migrate/s3.py", line 50, in save_image_from_url
    with open(os.path.join(IMG_DIR_ABS, filename), 'wb') as f:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How should I catch this error and continue my process. As I am running continued loop which gets stopped at this point. If there is a solution to save images from these url then its great otherwise please help me to bypass this error and continue my process. Inside my for loop I am importing this function from other file.

No after doing `sys.reload`, I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character at special name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137552/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-at-special-name)

Comment: Where does "filename" comes from ? If it's a unicode string, you want to make sure it's encoded in something your filesystem supports.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `urllib.quote(filename)` before saving it.

Comment: can you explain how

Comment: The earlier is the better. You can use it when calling the function : ``save_image_from_url(url, urllib.quote(filename))`` in line 340 or before, when initializing filename.

Comment: Yeah, great, a fugly workaround instead of properly solving the source problem... Learn about unicode and encodings instead, you'll save yourself a lot of pain.