# Django Model with a CharField gives unicode error if quote in string

Tags: django, unicode, django-models

This is my form which uses a model called `modelQuizQuestion`. This model has a `char` field in it. Now everything works fine if the char field in that model does not have a quote in it. Otherwise I get an exception on `form.is_valid()` which is

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)`

```
class DynamicQuizForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, patient, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DynamicQuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        question_qset = modelQuizQuestion.objects.filter(patient=patient)
        counter = 0
        for question in question_qset:
            counter+=1
            #Construct choices
            choice_qset = modelQuizChoice.objects.filter(question=question)
            main_choices = []
            for choice in choice_qset:
                small_choices = []
                small_choices.append(choice.choice)
                small_choices.append(choice.choice)
                main_choices.append(small_choices)

                self.fields[question.question] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=main_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(),)
```

and this is how I am using it

```
 if request.method == "POST":
    quizForm = DynamicQuizForm(patient=patient_qset, data=request.POST)
    if quizForm.is_valid(): #<------------ gives exception here
           .....
```

Any suggestions why this might be happening. 
I looked at these two links
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)
and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137552/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-at-special-name)

However it seems like it is a unicode issue and the answers recommend to use `decode` instead of `str`. Howeever in my code I am not using `str` anywhere

**Update**

I believe the reason for this issue is because of the statement

```
self.fields[question.question] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=main_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(),)
```

and this only occurs if `question.question` has a string with apostrophe in it.

This is the question model

```
class modelQuizQuestion(models.Model):
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(modelPatient,default=None,blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=800, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Questions in the Quizes"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Question : " +self.question
```

Any suggestions on how i can fix this ?

Comment: declare the # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*- in the file does not solve?

Comment: Nope it did not solve the problem

Comment: are you using python 2?

Answer (score 0):

Type on the first line of all files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Try to implement the following class:

```
class modelQuizQuestion(models.Model):
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(modelPatient,default=None,blank=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=800, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Questions in the Quizes"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Question: %s" % self.question
```

If you're using python 3 and you want it to be compatible with the python 2, use the decorator python2_unicode_compatible

```
from django.utils.encoding import python2_unicode_compatible

@python2_unicode_compatible
class modelQuizQuestion(models.Model): ...
```

If you have more questions, check the documentation for Django. I advise you take a look at Choosing between **str**() and **unicode**()

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/ref/unicode/