# 'UnicodeEncodeError' when using 'set_dataframe'

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, pygsheets

When using `set_dataframe` to update my Google Sheets via `pygsheets` and `pandas`, I get error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

This is due to `utf-8` marks over some text, e.g.,: "señor"

This happens on executing:

```
wks.set_dataframe(df, start='A10')
```

Pandas `to_csv` accepts an encoding parameter similar to `encoding="utf-8"`, may I suggests `set_dataframe` does the same?

```
wks.set_dataframe(df, start='A10', encoding="utf-8")
```

I see there's a ticket opened 10 days ago [here](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/327) but is there a workaround?

Comment: Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I ran into the same issue, and I think that, more than a bug in the pygsheets module, it would be a limitation as you clearly point out.

What I did to solve this issue was:

```
def encodeDataFrame(df, encoding='UTF-8'):
  if df is not None and not df.empty:
    for column, series in df.items():
      if type(series.at[0]) == unicode:
        try:
          encodedSeries = series.str.encode(encoding)
          df[column] = encodedSeries
        except Exception as e:
          print 'Could not encode column %s' % column
          raise
```

And you can call the function this way:

```
encodeDataFrame(df)
wks.set_dataframe(df, start='A10')
```

**This might no longer be a good solution because of a change that was made in `pygsheets` to avoid this issue. See EDIT section below**

**Explanation:**
You solve the issue by encoding the `unicode` values yourself, before sending them to the `set_dataframe` function.

This problem comes up whenever you try to use the `Worksheet.set_dataframe` [function](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.set_dataframe), using a dataframe that contains unicode characters that cannot be encoded in ascii (like accents, and many other).

The exception is thrown because the `set_dataframe` function attempts to cast the `unicode` values into `str` values (using the default encoding). For Python 2, the default encoding is `ascii` and when a character out of the range of `ascii` is found, the exception is thrown.

Some people have suggested [reloading the sys module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137935/7656369) to circumvent this problem, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378962/7656369) is explained why you should not do it

The other solution I would think of would be to use the pygsheets module in Python 3, where this should no longer be a problem because the default encoding for Python 3 is UTF-8 ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode))

**Bonus:**
Ask yourself:
1) Is Unicode an encoding?
2) What is an encoding?

If you hesitated with any of those questions, you should read [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), which gave me the knowledge needed to think of this solution. The time invested was completely worth it.

For more information, you can try [this article](https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html) which links to the previous one at the end.

**EDIT:**
A [change](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/commit/550deb2658845b58c5edc41682a7e9fafbfcfe40) was made 2 days ago (07/26/19) to `pygsheets` that is supposed to fix this. It looks like the intention is to avoid encoding into the `str` type, but I would think that this change might try decoding strings into the `unicode` type from the default ascii encoding, which could also lead to trouble. When/If this change is released it is probably going to be better not to encode anything and pass values as unicode to the `set_dataframe` function.

**EDIT 2:**
This change has now been released in version `2.0.2`. If my predictions were true, using the `encodeDataFrame` function I suggested will result in a `UnicodeDecodeError` because the `Worksheet.set_dataframe` function will attempt to decode the `str` values with the default `ascii` encoding. So the best way to use the function will be not to have any `str` values in your dataframe. If you have them, decode them to `unicode` before calling the `set_dataframe` function. You could have a mirror version of the 
function I suggested. It would look something like this:

```
def decodeDataFrame(df, encoding='UTF-8'):
  if df is not None and not df.empty:
    for column, series in df.items():
      if type(series.at[0]) == str:
        try:
          decodedSeries = series.str.decode(encoding)
          df[column] = decodedSeries
        except Exception as e:
          print 'Could not decode column %s' % column
          raise
```